# Retrieving custom field as shortcode

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, post-meta

I have added a custom field to my site called "dansk_url", to which a link to the version in Danish (different domain) will be entered. I would like to be able to output this as a shortcode to add anywhere within the post, and it should appear as a link (anchor text will always be "Dansk" and whichever url has been entered in the custom field for that post.

Is this possible? I prefer a non-plugin solution.

Comment: How did you add the custom field? Using custom code? If so, what's your code?

Comment: post some code so that other developers could see where you stuck at.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add any code. I used the instructions here [link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in `functions.php` of your theme.

```
add_shortcode( 'dansk_url', 'dansk_url' );
function dansk_url() {
    $output='';
    $the_url= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dansk_url', true );

    if ( $the_url)  $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $the_url) . '">Dansk</a>';

    return $output;
}
```

and use shortcode `[dansk_url]` in the post.

Comment: There's a syntax error here: `$output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $the_url) . '">Dansk</a>'` (missing `;` at the end)...

Comment: @SallyCJ, Stay blessed! Thanks for correction.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks a million!

Comment: @auntie glad to know that it worked. Please mark this answer as **Accepted Answer** an up-vote, to help other people searching for similar issue to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to be able to output this as a shortcode to add anywhere
>   within the post

So since you said, "*I prefer a non-plugin solution*", then you can use this (which you'd add to the theme `functions.php` file) to create the shortcode:

```php
add_shortcode( 'dansk_link', 'dansk_link_shortcode' );
function dansk_link_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    $url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dansk_url', true );
    if ( $url ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>">Dansk</a>
    <?php
    endif; // end $url
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

And in the post content, add `[dansk_link]` anywhere you like.

The above PHP code is still considered a plugin, but it's basically "your own" plugin. :)

PS: For the function reference, you can check [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) and [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

### UPDATE

1. I changed the shortcode name to `dansk_link` because that seems better than `dansk_url` for what the shortcode is for (i.e. outputting a *link*).
2. In my original answer, I used output buffering (i.e. those `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`) so that's it's easier for *you* (the question author) to edit the HTML output.

Having said the point #2 above, you could also use:

```php
add_shortcode( 'dansk_link', 'dansk_link_shortcode' );
function dansk_link_shortcode() {
    if ( $url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dansk_url', true ) ) {
        return '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">Dansk</a>';
    }
    return '';
}
```